# What languages to write a Portable Class Library

Tags: .net, portable-class-library

I have a classes written in c++ (vc++). Now, I would like to create Portable Class Library(PCL) from these classes.

My question : what languages I should use to write the PCL??

if I am not allowed to use c++ , what other alternatives ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you mean an app targeting the PCL? Any .NET language will do.

Comment: I mean the PCL itself.

Comment: Are you talking about [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg597391.aspx)? If you are, then sorry but your question makes no sense to me as the PCL is already written. It'd be just like asking *"How do I write mscorlib?"*.

Comment: I am probably mistaken but think only C# and VB.NET is supported at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Visual Studio 2013 Update 3* supports *Universal* library projects in C++, be it in the form of a static *.lib* library, dynamic *.dll* library or a [Windows Runtime Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh441569.aspx), *.winmd*. *Universal* libraries can be used in modern *Windows 8* and *Windows Phone 8.1* applications alike.

Other platforms, such as the traditional .NET desktop, Silverlight or Xamarin cannot be targeted with the *Universal* libraries.

If you want to be able to target any of these other platforms, you would need to fall back on regular *Portable Class Library*, PCL, projects. *Visual Studio* currently supports PCL projects written in C#, Visual Basic and F#.